# Get original less files from minified css + sourcemap file

Tags: npm, webpack, less

I accidentaly deleted less files, but still have the css-minified file and the sourcemaps file.

With chrome developper tools, i can view original less files and its content, thanks to sourcemaps.

Is there a way to de-compile the entire css file, and get the original file structure ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`source-map`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map). Take a look at the consumer, which you can instantiate with the raw JSON data, and the method [`consumer.sourceContentFor('foo.js')`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map#sourcemapconsumerprototypesourcecontentforsource-returnnullonmissing) which will attempt to return the source contents.